# Print all environment variables but skipping multiline variables

Tags: bash, loops, unix, environment-variables, multiline

I want to print all environment variables except certain variables.

Therefore I found a solution on stackoverflow: [Bash: loop through variables containing pattern in name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25765282/bash-loop-through-variables-containing-pattern-in-name)

```bash
while IFS='=' read -r name value; do
    if [ ! "$name" = "SOMEVAR" -a ! "$name" = "SOMEOTHERVAR" ]; then
        echo "$name=$value"
    fi
done < <(env)
```

However this does not work if my environment variables contain newlines, such as:

```bash
export SOMEVAR="some
text with
newlines"
```

With the above solution it would print:

```bash
text with=
newlines=
PWD=/home/...
...
```

I also tried to use null-terminated strings and multiline matching with `sed`:

```bash
env -0 | sed -e '{N; s@SOMEVAR.*\x0@@ ; D}' | tr '\0' '\n'
```

But this cuts off the output and always prints the last line of a variable with multiline content at first:

```bash
newlines
PWD=/home/...
...
```

Is there any way to skip multiline environment variables while printing them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You almost had it, you just need to loop over the output of `env -0` with a read command and null delimiter and exclude the variables using the regex operator

```
while read -r -d '' line; do 
    [[ ! $line =~ ^(SOMEVAR|SOMEOTHERVAR)= ]] && printf '%s\n' "$line" 
done < <(env -0)
```

The `read` command with `d ''` implies delimit the input on the null delimit character. The while loop runs until the last delimited line is parsed.

Also this just *prints* all the variables excluding the ones you want to avoid. For further processing of each of the lines, you can parse out the `$line` variable to split the *key*/*value* pairs and use it accordingly.

Or if your intention was to identify *any* variable containing a multi-line string, you can exclude that with the regex as

```
[[ ! $line =~ $'\n' ]]
```

Comment: Thanks for you solution! Its working as long other variables do not start with `SOMEVAR`, for example `SOMEVAR2` would not be printed. I fixed this by using the expression `^(SOMEVAR|SOMEOTHERVAR)=` instead. If you agree, you may add this to your answer? Also thanks for the alternative solution to filter every variable with multiline content!

Answer (score 1):

You may use bash builtin `compgen` which outputs all env variable names when used with `-v` option so:

```
compgen -v # prints all variable names
```

Now you can easily use this in a loop to exclude unwanted names and print rest:

```
while read var; do
   echo "$var=${!var}"
done < <(compgen -v | grep -vxFE '(SOMEVAR|SOMEOTHERVAR)')
```

Comment: Unfortunately at my environment `compgen -v` gives me twice more variables than `env`. For example `BASH_ARGC`, `LINES`, `RANDOM` or the git completion variables. Nevertheless its a nice solution and I did not know that `compgen -v` does something similar to `env`, thanks!